# How to generate random values of specific distribution with Scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I want to generate a random number following a lognormal distribution with Scipy. I understand from the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) that you can use:

```
import scipy.stats
R = scipy.stats.lognorm.rvs()
```

But I want to use specific parameters. I cannot find an example. This is what I want to do:

```
params = (0.6718101713289113, -3.5861418072007032, 44.598580116376482)
R = scipy.stats.lognorm.rvs(params)
```

But this does not work. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only pass one parameter, a tuple, to rvs. You have to unpack the tuple:

```
R = scipy.stats.lognorm.rvs(*params)
```

Comment: It works Thx. What does the * stand for? Is it like in C, a reference to the tuple?